# It's possible to increment a declaration of a variable?

Tags: php, for-loop, while-loop, do-while

I'm new in php this is possible?

```
$value_0 = "0"; 
$value_1 = "1";
$value_2 = "2"; 
$nr = 2;
    for ($i=0; $i <= $nr; $i++)
    {
        echo "$value_$i";
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of **naming** variables like you did, there's something called an `array`.

Instead of having :

```
$value_0 = "0"; 
$value_1 = "1";
$value_2 = "2";
```

you'd have:

```
$value[0] = "0";
$value[1] = "1";
$value[2] = "2";
```

Since you're new to PHP, you should start using tools that PHP gives you. You wanted to iterate your variables by utilizing a numerical index - which is fine. The issue lies in naming your variables.

An array lends you a hand here, it's a way of referencing multiple variables under the same name.

If you haven't read or heard about it, head on to [PHP documentation page about arrays](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php).

Using arrays, your code would look like this:

```
$value[0] = "0";
$value[1] = "1";
$value[2] = "2";
$nr = 2;

for ($i=0; $i <= $nr; $i++)
{
    echo $value[$i];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$value_0 = 0;
$value_1 = 1;
$value_2 = 2; 
$nr = 2;
    for ($i=0; $i <= $nr; $i++)
    {
        echo ${"value_" . $i};
        echo '<br>';
    }
?>
```

Wrap them in {}

Answer (score 0):

You can have this simply like this

```
    echo ${value_.$i};
```